# Residence has changed - Must I re-apply for ESTA?

Tags: usa, visas, legal, esta

I have an old, but still valid ESTA, with the country of residence showing my home country. However, I have recently moved for education in the UK. Do I have to apply for a new one?

Nothing else has changed - country of citizenship, passport, names etc

Comment: Contacted US Embassy. No reapplication / amendment needed in my case.

Answer (score 9):

Nope.  I've changed my residency from UK, to NZ, to Canada in the last 1.5 years, and have used my ESTA as recently as last week, and it's fine.  It's tied solely to your passport/citizenship.  I was open about my changes at the border, my Canadian permit is even in my passport, and they were totally fine.

Of course, once your ESTA is more than two years old (as mine will be in November) you'll have to apply for a new one :/

It seems weird that we don't need visas, but we have to pay $US14 for a visa-waiver.  Sounds like a visa to me (rant) :)

Comment: The majority of the $14 goes towards promotion of tourism in the US. The real "advantage" of the ESTA not being a visa is that if your ESTA application is refused, then you have NOT been refused a visa. Whilst that sounds like semantics, it's extremely important when you then do go to apply for a US visa!